# Mac OS X trouble with certain hotspots

Tags: macos, routing, ip

As an admin, it bugs me horribly when I personally have network issues I can't explain/get decipher - maybe you guys can shed some light.

Running a MacBook Air with the newest incarnation of Mac OS X (Mavericks), I sometime run into issues with public WiFi Hotspots. 
Basically, I connect to certain WiFi Hotspot, but don't really get a connection - no IP traffic is going through. Here is what i gathered so far:

In the non-working case, my routing table looks like this:

```
Shu:~ blitz$ netstat -nr
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
169.254            link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
192.168.182        link#4             UC              0        0     en0
192.168.182        link#4             UCSI            2        0     en0
192.168.182.1      20:4e:7f:8b:36:81  UHLWIir         1      208     en0    992
192.168.182.240    127.0.0.1          UHS             0        0     lo0
192.168.182.255    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        1     en0

Internet6:
Destination                             Gateway                         Flags         Netif Expire
::1                                     ::1                             UHL             lo0
fe80::%lo0/64                           fe80::1%lo0                     UcI             lo0
fe80::1%lo0                             link#1                          UHLI            lo0
fe80::%en0/64                           link#4                          UCI             en0
fe80::1%en0                             50:7e:5d:95:45:2                UHLWI           en0
fe80::1240:f3ff:fe81:df32%en0           10:40:f3:81:df:32               UHLI            lo0
fe80::26ab:81ff:feb9:1b0%en0            24:ab:81:b9:1:b0                UHLWI           en0
fe80::5a55:caff:fe53:96e6%en0           58:55:ca:53:96:e6               UHLWI           en0
fe80::5e96:9dff:fe70:108a%en0           5c:96:9d:70:10:8a               UHLWI           en0
ff01::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI            lo0
ff01::%en0/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en0
ff02::%lo0/32                           ::1                             UmCI            lo0
ff02::%en0/32                           link#4                          UmCI            en0
```

A ping to the local router (`192.168.182.1`) lead to this output:

```
shu:~ blitz$ ping 192.168.182.1
PING 192.168.182.1 (192.168.182.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.182.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=3.026 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.182.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=3.323 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.182.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3.147 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.182.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3.227 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 192.168.182.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=3.085 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.182.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=3.975 ms (DUP!)
```

And the corresponding tcpdump during the ping shows this:

```
Shu:~ blitz$ sudo tcpdump
tcpdump: data link type PKTAP
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on pktap, link-type PKTAP (Packet Tap), capture size 65535 bytes
12:59:19.180358 IP 192.168.182.240 > 192.168.182.1: ICMP echo request, id 30483, seq 223, length 64
12:59:19.183449 IP 192.168.182.1 > 192.168.182.240: ICMP echo reply, id 30483, seq 223, length 64
12:59:19.183530 IP 192.168.182.1 > 192.168.182.240: ICMP echo reply, id 30483, seq 223, length 64
12:59:20.181503 IP 192.168.182.240 > 192.168.182.1: ICMP echo request, id 30483, seq 224, length 64
12:59:20.184755 IP 192.168.182.1 > 192.168.182.240: ICMP echo reply, id 30483, seq 224, length 64
12:59:20.184758 IP 192.168.182.1 > 192.168.182.240: ICMP echo reply, id 30483, seq 224, length 64
```

Now, when the connection works (which it sometimes does or which it does with other WiFis) I see this routing table:

```
shu:~ blitz$ netstat -nr
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
default            192.168.1.1        UGSc           33        5     en0
169.254            link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
192.168.1          link#4             UCS             2        0     en0
192.168.1.1        84:7a:88:66:c5:79  UHLWIir        34       66     en0   1170
192.168.1.150      127.0.0.1          UHS             1       25     lo0
192.168.1.255      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0       16     en0
```

My guess it the duplicated `192.168.182` line in the first netstat - but first of all, how does it get there, second what does it really do and third how do I get rid of it (besides rebooting, which is just crude :))

Comment: It's not you, it's the hotspot. Two machines are replying to its IP address. This is going to cause all sorts of chaos.

Comment: Nope, can't be it - rebooting my machine, and it works again - with the same IP! That's the really foo'd part about it.